# Border effect to let a picture stand out?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a special `CSS` (3?) border effect: when applied, it looked like the corners of the objects stand out a bit more then the middle of the sides. Which produces a nice effect as if a piece of paper would be lying on the website.

How do you call this effect?

Comment: can you show us that effect by any image or anything else?

Comment: if I'd know the keyword to find an image, I'd also find the css sources. I just forgot the name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page contains a good looking "bent paper" shadow effect, with pure CSS:

http://matthamm.com/box-shadow-curl.html

Sample code for the shadow effect on `<li>` element from the source above:

HTML:

```
<ul class="box">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.box {
position: relative;
z-index: 1; /* prevent shadows falling behind containers with backgrounds */
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }


ul.box li {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 250px;
height: 150px;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #efefef;
margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
background: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset; }


ul.box li:before,
ul.box li:after {
content: '';
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
width: 70%;
max-width: 300px; /* avoid rotation causing ugly appearance at large container widths */
max-height: 100px;
height: 55%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
-o-transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg); }


ul.box li:after {
left: auto;
right: 10px;
-webkit-transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
-moz-transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
-ms-transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
-o-transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg); }
```

Note: If you are using a parent element. Make sure that the parent div has position: relative; z-index: 99; or those shadows won’t show up.

Comment: Please post relevant code here, external links might not work in the future, which will make your answer useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS3 box-shadow and transforms. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div {
  width: 215px; 
  height: 80px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  position: relative; 
  background: white;
}

div::before, div::after {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 12px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
}

div::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JuwLd

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a little trick of setting the border width to different sizes. For example:

```
div{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/du69V/)

Don't know how this is called, though.

Comment: That is not what TS meant, I'm afraid.